# PDFtron Xamarin Forrm Customize QuickMenu

Tags: pdftron

Am trying to customize the quickmenu to remove some menu items in PDFtron 9.0.2, following the guide [here](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/guides/advanced/customize-quick-menu/#override-menu-resources).

[image]

Tried first to add pan.xml under resources folder and it is not working.

[image]

Tried subscribing to *ShowQuickMenu* event and remove some unwanted menu and it is also not working.

```
mDocumentView.MPdfViewCtrlTabHostFragment.CurrentPdfViewCtrlFragment.ShowQuickMenu += CurrentPdfViewCtrlFragment_ShowQuickMenu;
```

Event handler

```
var menu = e.Quickmenu.Menu as QuickMenuBuilder;
var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.qm_redaction);
item.SetVisible(false);
```

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Following code works.

```
var redactionMenuItem = e.Quickmenu.FindMenuItem(Resource.Id.qm_redaction);

e.Quickmenu.RemoveMenuEntries(new List<QuickMenuItem> { redactionMenuItem });
```

*Dont know why customizing *pan.xml* is not working though.*